# NGINX in Openshift - NGINX can't resolve internal hostnames

Tags: nginx, dns, openshift, openshift-origin, resolver

When using a variable to rewrite & proxy to an internal Openshift service within an nginx container's proxy_pass config, NGINX can't resolve the service's DNS due to a required resolver. For instance:

```
location /api/ {
   set $pass_url http://service.namespace.svc:8080$request_uri;
   proxy_pass  $pass_url;
}
```

When using standard Kubernetes, I can use `kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local`as the resolver:

```
resolver kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local;
```

But Openshift doesn't provide this. I've tried using the IP that is in the container's `/etc/resolv.conf`, which is just one of the nodes in my cluster that is running the DNS server, but it still can't resolve.

Weirdest part is `nslookup service.namespace.svc` from inside the container terminal uses the nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf` and it works fine.

Is there an equivalent to the Kubernetes DNS hostname in Openshift I could use, or perhaps another solution to work around this?

Answer (score 3):

Running ngnix in OpenShift 4.7 I was able to work around this issue by adding

`resolver  dns-default.openshift-dns.svc.cluster.local`

to the `server` configuration. Apparently, ngnix is not parsing `/etc/resolv.conf`, but (in my case), `dns-default.openshift-dns.svc.cluster.local` also resolves to `172.30.0.10`, which was defined as a `nameserver` in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

In Openshift cluster there is SkyDNS service on each master node. It normally listens on port 8053. Just use them as the resolver for nginx config and you will be fine:

```
resolver your-openshift-master-node1-ip:8053 your-openshift-master-node2-ip:8053;
```

Answer (score -2):

From https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/networking/networking.html#architecture-additional-concepts-openshift-dns, it looks like the following should work

```
<service>.<pod_namespace>.svc.cluster.local
```